# Determine source of data corruption in Metatag module

Tags: database, caching, meta-tags

I've run into data corruption issues on my site that seem to be stemming from the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module. I've currently disabled Metatag and its associated modules, but previously, in addition to the base Metatag module, I'd also been using the Facebook, Panels, Verification, and OpenGraph Metatag functionality.

The reason I believe it to be related to Metatag is that the hosting support tech helping troubleshoot initially solved the issue of mysql crashing and restarting by truncating the `cache_metatag` table. The site was fine for a few days, then again I saw the issue of mysql crashing. To try to stem any further issues, I disabled the Metatag Facebook, Panels, Verification, & OpenGraph modules. This brought the site down entirely and hosting support had to dump all of the databases and re-import. As this process cleared any temporary data, presumably, the problematic cache table was truncated again.

Without being able to replicate consistently, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot or pinpoint the problem enough to submit an issue on the project.

- How can I go about pinpointing an issue like this?
- Is disabling these modules enough to prevent data corruption in an associated cache table? Sorry if that's a silly question, my guess is that cache data wouldn't be generated if disabled, but I want to be sure to prevent any further data corruption + site downtime.

Comment: Any errors in the log `/admin/reports/dblog` ?

Comment: No, it seems like the data corruption is bringing down mysql at such a point that nothing gets logged there.